# Horizontally centering a node in a TikZ diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment

I manged to draw this diagram with tikz:

[image]
with this code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, 
    text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]


\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 5cm, scale=0.1]
    % Place nodes
    \node  [block](trr) {Node};
    \node  [block] (trr1) [below of=trr] {A};
    \node  [block] (trr2) [left of=trr1] {B};    
    \node  [block] (trr3) [right of=trr1] {C};      
    %\node  [block] (trr4) [right of=trr3] {D};        
    % Draw edges
    \path [line] (trr) -- (trr1);
    \path [line] (trr) -- (trr2);
    \path [line] (trr) -- (trr3);
    %\path [line] (trr) -- (trr4);
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

I would like that the block **Node** remains centered, and that I have 4 elements (**A**,**B**,**C** and **D**) in the second row. How can I achieve this?

Uncommenting the line

```
\node  [block] (trr4) [right of=trr3] {D};
```

and

```
\path [line] (trr) -- (trr4);
```

results in [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You actually draw a tree .. so see if code below gives desired result:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,
               tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
every node/.style = {rectangle, draw, rounded corners, 
                     fill=blue!20,
                     text width=3em, minimum height=2em, 
                     align=center},
edge from parent/.style= {draw, -latex'}
                        ]
\node (trr) {Node}
    child {node (trr1) {A}}
    child {node (trr2) {B}}
    child {node (trr3) {C}}
    child {node (trr4) {D}};
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Addendum:
After five (!) years I notice, that you like to have arrow at child ends on north of nodes. Using `forest package` this can be simply to o achieve:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree = {
% nodes
    draw, rounded corners, fill=blue!20,
    text width=3em, minimum height=2em, text centered,
% tree
    child anchor = north,
    edge={-Latex},
    l sep=11mm,
    s sep=1mm
            }
[Node
    [A] [B] [C] [D]
]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you perfect!! I don't even have to specify the edges now. Do you know if its easy to tell that the arrow of each edge should be at the center of the child( so for instance that the left arrow is above **A**).

Comment: @Adam, I'm very sorry but I only noticed your note now (after five years!)

Comment: haha no worries, my times with Latex are over ;)